# If() Condition Not getting True

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am New in IOS i am facing a problem.
I have 3 GMGridViews on my Xib and i got reference in .m file of my ViewControllar Now in Delegates and DataSource Methods when i put Check on it if condition not getting true for 2 GMViewControllars but become true for 1st one. i try isEqual: also instead of " == "
 Here is my Code

```
#pragma mark GMGridViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInGMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView
{
    if (gridView==self.artistFollowingGM) {
        return 4;//[self.artistFollowingArray count];
    }else  if (gridView==self.followersGM) {
        return 5;// [self.membersFollowingArray count];
    }else if(gridView==self.repostedGM){
        return 10; //[self.repostedArray count];
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Datasource and delegates are same for all then why if is not getting true for 2 GMGrids??

Comment: Are the IBOutlets properly connected and the datasource and delegate properties set for each of the three GMGridViews in the interface builder?

Comment: Yup IBOutlets connected and properties set. i checked it

Comment: Your code looks OK; it's not obvious what the issue is.  Have you looked at the different values involved here (i.e. `gridView`, `self.artistFollowingGM`, etc?).

Comment: Need more detail, for now can not tell what's wrong.

Comment: tag all gridview& check here if(gridview.tag == 1){} elseif()

Answer (score 0):

Try to set tag upon different GridViews, and then compare tag instead of reference, it quickly solves out your problem. for example

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInGMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView
{
    if ([gridView tag] == 1) {
        return 4;//[self.artistFollowingArray count];
    }
    else  if ([gridView tag] == 2) {
        return 5;// [self.membersFollowingArray count];
    }
    else if([gridView tag] == 3){
        return 10; //[self.repostedArray count];
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this help?  Are you suggesting comparing using `==` won't work?

Comment: by comparing `reference`, its difficult to debug, well if we perform comparison by using `tag` value its a lot easier to do.

Comment: Not really, they are both just numbers.

Comment: one number with `hexadecimal` notation assigned by system( varying every time) and one number you assigned yourself have huge difference of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. I was setting `datasource` and `delegates` from `Xib` but after writing this line problem is solved now.

```
self.followersGM.dataSource = self;
self.followersGM.delegate = self;
```